# my javascript function is not displaying all validation messages

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, dom-traversal

So if both validations work seperatley (if I just put radio buttons validation in the function without the spinner validation then radio buttons validation works and same vise versa), how come when I put both validations in the function, the top validation which is the radio validation works but the bottom validation which is the spinner validation does not display a message when it is suppose to?

```
Code is below:

        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
                <title>Create a Session</title>
                        <script type="text/javascript">

    function validation() {
                    var errMsgO = document.getElementById("radioAlert");
                    var btnRadioO = document.getElementsByName("sessionNo");               
                    var isbtnRadioChecked = false;
                    var errQuesMsgO = document.getElementById("numberAlert");
                    var questionNumberO = document.getElementsByName("txtQuestion");

                    for(i=0; i < btnRadioO.length; i++){
                        if(btnRadioO[i].checked){
                            isbtnRadioChecked = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if(!isbtnRadioChecked) {
                       errMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select the Number of Sessions you Require";
                    } else {
                        errMsgO.innerHTML = "";
                    }
                    return false; 



        if(questionNumberO[0].value == 0){
            errQuesMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Set the Number of Questions";
        } else {
            errQuesMsgO.innerHTML = "";
        }
           return false; 
                }    
</script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form action="create_session.php" method="post" name="sessionform">
    <table>
              <tr>
              <th>2: Number of Sessions :</th>
              <td class="sessionNo"><input type="radio" name="sessionNo" value="1" />1</td>
              <td class="sessionNo"><input type="radio" name="sessionNo" value="2" />2</td>
              <td class="sessionNo"><input type="radio" name="sessionNo" value="3" />3</td>
              <td class="sessionNo"><input type="radio" name="sessionNo" value="4" />4</td>
              <td class="sessionNo"><input type="radio" name="sessionNo" value="5" />5</td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              <div id="radioAlert"></div>
        <table>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Number of Questions:</th>
                        <td class="spinner"><textarea class="spinnerQuestion" name="txtQuestion" id="txtQuestion" cols="2" rows="1"></textarea></td>
                        <td><button class="scrollBtn" id="btnQuestionUp"><img src="Images/black_uppointing_triangle.png" alt="Increase" /></button>
                        <button class="scrollBtn" id="btnQuestionDown"><img src="Images/black_downpointing_triangle.png" alt="Decrease" /></button></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div id="numberAlert"></div>
                        <p><input class="questionBtn" type="button" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" onClick="validation()" /></p>      <!-- Prepare Questions here-->

                </form>
        </body>
```

Comment: An array of DOM elements will never equal zero.

Comment: Also, if the input is expected to be a number, why not just put it into a text input instead of a text area?

Comment: When I researched spinners it used a textarea rather than a text input box. I will change in later on. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one mistake I could spot is the line `if(questionNumberO == 0){` (*besides you have not closed your `<script>` element with `</script>`*).

**The correct way is:**

```
if(questionNumberO[0].value == 0){
```

**Why:**

[`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) will return a collection of elements with the specified `name` attribute. If you know there is only one, you can ask for the first one (`[0]`).

The `value` property stores the current value of an input element. See [HTMLInputElement on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement).

**Update:** I have created a [working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VJ7Vn/) for you.

Comment: It still isn't displaying a message below. I can't see any typos though so must be another way to do it. Nice try tho

Comment: Please check my Fiddle, which works. Compare it to your code. I have changed basically two things, those that I mentioned.

Comment: The value of a textarea will never be 0 either--I'd feel more comfortable if there was explicit conversion.

Comment: @Dave He uses a spinner on it, so it might be. `'' == 0` will also be true in Javascript. You're right about it though, I was trying to concentrate on fixing the code.

Comment: @bazmegakapa I know it will, but if the value is saved and used anywhere with `===` etc. it'll value; just seems consistently safer to perform the actual conversion. YMMV.

Comment: Ah no sorry, it does work. What happens is that I had another validation above this one in the same function which checks for radio buttons. If I remove the radio buttons validation so I only have this validation in the function then it works but if I include the radio buttons validation in the function then it doesn't work. I will sort this out but your answer is correct. Thank You